# Can this implementation be something like di injection?

Tags: c#

I have this code, is it dependency injection or not? I want to get data from different sources by interface.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Data D = new Data();
        AnotherApplication AS = new AnotherApplication(D);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public interface IData
{
    WebSocket WebSocket { get; }
}

public class Data:IData
{
    public WebSocket WebSocket
    {
        get
        {
            var temp = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:2012");
            temp.Open();
            return temp;
        }
    }
}
public class AnotherApplication
{
    public AnotherApplication(IData source)
    {
        source.WebSocket.MessageReceived += ProcessMessage;
    }
    public void ProcessMessage(object o,EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Another happening");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Yes, it seems like a method injection.

Comment: But interface have property? Why method?

Comment: It doesn't matter what your interface representation is. DI relies on injecting abstraction to either constructor, property or method. You are injection `IData` to the method.